# How do I call a specific value from a dictionary inside a dictionary?

Tags: python-2.7

Currently am trying to make code which can pick out either specific or aggregate values for certain actions. I am using a nested dictionary for this, but am having issues calling specific values of nested dictionary. The code runs, but always brings the same value, not matter which key I originally tried to call

I have tried to have it print a variable set to the value of the key in the dictionary. I have also tried to use v.get() to retrieve the value from the dictionary.

```py
properties={'lake':{'repairs':9001,'upgrades':3,'police investigations':69}
            ,'meadow':{'repairs':3,'upgrades':8}
            ,'beach':{'repairs':4,'upgrades':2}
            ,'country':{'repairs':5,'upgrades':54}}

choice=raw_input('Do you want to learn about a specific property or total actions? (type specific or total) ')
choice=choice.lower()
if choice[0]=='s':
    for k,v in properties.items():
        print(properties.keys())
        properti=raw_input('Which property would you like to look at? (enter nothing to exit) ')
        print properties[properti]
        action=raw_input('What action is it you want to learn about? ')
        result=v[action]
        print('The '+properti+' property has had '+str(result)+' '+action+' completed.')
```

I expect when I call for a specific property, choose lake, then choose repairs, that I'd get the 9001. Or even going for meadow, I'd get 3 repairs. Currently I am always getting the country property's amounts for both repairs and upgrades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following

```
result=v[action]
```

to

```
result=properties[properti][action]
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked, but would you mind explaining why? I've just began coding about 2 months ago, and have only last week gotten to dictionaries.

Comment: Let me try, by `result = v[action]` you are taking the values from current iteration instead of taking values from the selected property. 
Suppose the for loop is at iteration `k='lake',v={'repairs':9001,'upgrades':3,'police investigations':69}` and you enter **country** for _properti_ and **repairs** for _action_, `v[action]` will give 9001 which is from current iteration instead of 5,
whereas you need to get the values of a selected property i.e. for **country**. So `result=properties[properti][action]` translates to `result = properties['country']['repairs']`. Hope i am clear enough.

Comment: Ah! I thought it was going to be something like that, but that makes sense. Thank you